# Docker images have different names

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am a beginner in Docker and following the Data Engineering Zoomcamp tutorial.I am running following command through powershell
docker run -it test:pandas
I can see a new container with **suspicious name** on Docker desktop app, refer to the image below
[image] . Is this normal ? Why is this happening . Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a container, Docker generates a unique name for it that looks like those. That allows you to run the same image multiple times. You can set the name yourself using the `--name` parameter on the `docker run` command if you want to set a name yourself.

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name---name

Also, please note that it's not the *image* that has different names as you say in your topic. It's the containers. You can have multiple containers running that are instances of the same image. The second column in your screenshot shows the image name, which is the same for both containers.